# jQuery how to wrap multiple tags in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example markup

```
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<input>
<input>
<h2>title 2</h2>
<input>
```

And it needs to be the following

```
<div>
  <h2>Title 1</h2>
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>title 2</h2>
  <input>
</div>
```

The amount of input fields is variable, and I can set a class on the h2's

I already tried it with `.wrap()` and `.wrapAll()` but that wraps each element together or each element seperate.

Other questions on SO that have a similar problem dont have variable inputs and can use next() or whatever.

The divs all need to be seperate accordions in case that changes things

e:
So far this:
`$('#id').nextUntil('.title').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='hihi'></div>");`
Works for one of the two elements. Might need an `each()`?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I needed to fiddle around with it longer before posting a question...

```
$("h2").each(function(i, el){
  $(el).nextUntil('.title').andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='hihi'></div>");
});
```

Worked for me.